# sass css map to store images sizes

Tags: css, sass

I am trying store images and sizes with sass, right now I can load all, but I would like be more specific and be able to load different images in my `.logo` class

like for example define what image will load in the class like twitter or google.

```
$logos: (
  twitter:  ( width:200px, height:100px,background-image: url('twitter.png')),
  google:   ( width:600px, height:200px,background-image: url('google.png'))

);

        @each $social, $icon in $logos {
                .logo {
                    width: map-get($icon, width);
                    height: map-get($icon, height);
                    background-image:map-get($icon,background-image);
                }
        }
```

output:

```
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("twitter.png");
}

.logo {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("google.png");
}
```

output I want:

//twitter logo if I define that above.

```
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("twitter.png");
}
```

// google logo if I define that above too

```
.logo {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("google.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: if you just wanted to add a comment above your the .logo code
>   just add `/*#{$social}*/` above `.logo` in your `@each-loop`.
>   Example output:
>
> ```
> /*twitter*/
> .logo {
>   width: 200px;
>   height: 100px;
>   background-image: url("twitter.png");
> }
> ```

do you want something like this compiled?

```
.logo.twitter{---}
```

if you wrap your variable inside a `#{}` you can use it!

Example:

```
    $logos: (
  twitter:  ( width:200px, height:100px,background-image: url('twitter.png')),
  google:   ( width:600px, height:200px,background-image: url('google.png'))

);
@each $social, $icon in $logos {

  .logo.#{$social}{
     width: map-get($icon, width);
     height: map-get($icon, height);
     background-image:map-get($icon,background-image);
    }
 }
```

outputs

```
.logo.twitter {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("twitter.png");
}

.logo.google {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("google.png");
}
```

you can also only use your `$social` variable, just remove `.logo` in your `@each` loop and you'll get

```
.twitter {
 ...
}

.google {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but  what I am trying to do is like this: 
.logo {@include twitter;} an this load the twitter defo. understand?

Comment: so, i tried a little, and it seems you can't use an @include with the #{social} variable or create dynamic variables for that matter. I also have to admit that i'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve? Do you only want to add the data sometimes? otherwise this would seem like a fitting solution